# Semaphore without exception on overflowing to max value

Tags: c#, semaphore

I require to use semaphore in my application which includes multiple threads. My usage might be a common scenario, but m stuck with the APIs.

In my usage, the semaphore can be posted from multiple spots, whereas there is only one thread which waits on the semaphore.

Now, I require the semaphore to be a binary one, i.e., I need to make sure that in case multiple threads post to the semaphore simultaneously, the semaphore count remains at one, and no error is thrown. How can I accomplish this.

In short I require the following code to work.

```
private static Semaphore semaphoreResetMapView = new Semaphore(0, 1);  // Limiting the max value of semaphore to 1.

void threadWait(){
    while (true){
        semaphoreResetMapView.WaitOne();
        <code>
    }
}

void Main(){

    tThread = new Thread(threadWait);
    tThread.Start();

    semaphoreResetMapView.Release(1);
    semaphoreResetMapView.Release(1);
    semaphoreResetMapView.Release(1);  // Multiple Releases should not throw an error. Rather saturate the value of semaphore to 1.
}
```

I will appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) rather than a `Semaphore`.

Comment: I have later realised that AutoResetEvent is actually the correct solution...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you don't really need a semaphore - you just need an [`AutoResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx). Your "posting" threads would just call [`Set`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.set.aspx), and the waiting thread would call [`WaitOne`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.waitone.aspx).

Or you could just use [`Monitor.Wait`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.wait.aspx) and [`Monitor.Pulse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.pulse.aspx)...

Comment: I suppose you meant ManualResetEvent, rather than AutoResetEvent.. One of the comments to the question answered it for me. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @vishal: No, I meant `AutoResetEvent`, which is closer to a semaphore than `ManualResetEvent`. (In a semaphore, if you call `WaitOne` multiple times without any `Release` operations, you'd expect the second call to block, right?)

Comment: Right. I agree. Infact I just realised that even for my current solution AUtoResetEvent fits in much better than ManualResetEvent. Thanks.